# Heroku Clojure REPL quits right away

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

When I run `heroku run lein repl` on my Clojure app hosted on Heroku, I'm seeing it quit without being able to access the REPL. Here's the output:

```
$heroku run lein repl
Running lein repl on ... up, run.7753
Downloading Leiningen to .lein/leiningen-2.6.1-standalone.jar now...
<Retrieving a bunch of poms and jars>
/app/.lein/bin/lein: line 58:    27 Killed                  $LEIN_JAVA_CMD -XX:+TieredCompilation $LEIN_JVM_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false -Dmaven.wagon.rto=10000 -Dleiningen.original.pwd="$PWD" -Dleiningen.trampoline-file="$TRAMPOLINE_FILE" -cp "$CLASSPATH" clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main "$@"
$
```

Comment: If you want to avoid downloading deps each time, you can run `heroku config:set LEIN_INCLUDE_IN_SLUG="yes"`. It will increase the size of the slug, but may help memory profile.

Comment: Great tip, will check it out. It's kind of nuts how much more memory running `lein repl` takes compared to our web node. It's < 400 MB for the web node vs > 2 GB for the repl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Heroku process was running out of memory as I was on a 1x dyno. Running with the following allows the REPL to start:

```
heroku run lein repl --size=standard-2x
```

Error message at the console isn't too helpful, but the heroku logs pointed to a memory issue.